# Processes in C for Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: c, linux

Here is what I am trying to do:

> Write a C program that takes an integer command line argument n,
>   spawns n processes that will each generate a random numbers between
>   -100 and 100, and then computes and prints out the sum of these random numbers. Each process needs to print out the random number it
>   generates.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int command,processCheck; // processCheck: to check if fork was successful or not and to 
    char * strNumProcess = NULL;// check the status of child process
    while((command = getopt(argc, argv, "n:"))!=-1){
        if(command == 'n'){
            strNumProcess = optarg;
            break;
        }
    }

    int numProcess = atoi(strNumProcess);

    int pipes[numProcess][2];


    int randomNum; // Variable to store the random number
    int randomNumSum=0; // Initialized variable to store the sum of random number

    /** A loop that creates specified number of processes**/
    for(int i=0; i<numProcess; i++){
        processCheck = fork(); // creates a child process. Usually fork() = 2^n processes
        if(processCheck < 0){ // Checks for the error in fork()
            printf("Error");
            exit(1); // Terminates with error
        }
        else if(processCheck == 0){
            close(pipes[i][0]);
        /** Child process**/
            srand(time(NULL)+getpid()); // sets the randomness of the number associted with process id
            randomNum = rand()% 201 + (-100); // sets the range of random number from -100 to 100 and stores the random number in randomNum
            printf("%d\n" , randomNum); // Prints out the random number
            write(pipes[i][1], &randomNum, sizeof randomNum);
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            exit(0);// Terminates successfully
        }
        else{
            if(wait(NULL)){ // Waits for the child process to end and directs to parent process
                int v;
                if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v)==sizeof(v)){
                    randomNumSum+=v;
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                }
            }
        }
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }

    printf("%d\n", randomNumSum); // Prints the sum of the random number

    return 0;
}
```

The program goes in infinite loop after second process.

Comment: Hint: `randomNum = rand()% 199 + (-100);` => `-100 -> 98`.

Comment: so `randomNum = rand()%201+(-100);` => `-100->100`?

Comment: Yes!! You got it .. Good job. Recall `rand() % n` returns `0 -> n-1`.

Answer (score 3):

**edit**

The OP has made significant changes to the question, it's not the same question as it was yesterday. This answer might henceforth make no sense any more.

**end edit**

The reason for this is that `fork()` creates a new independent process with its
own virtual memory. It only inherits the values from the parent, the forked process do not share variables
with the parents. So `randomNumSum` is for every child a unique variable and
changing it does not affect the `randomNumSum` of the parent.

You need to use for example pipes for communication between parents and
children, the children write the results in the pipe, the parent reads from the
children.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s num_of_children\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    int noc = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(noc <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of children\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int pipes[noc][2];
    pid_t pids[noc];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < noc; ++i)
    {
        if(pipe(pipes[i]) == -1)
        {
            perror("pipe");
            pids[i] = -2; // used later for error checking
            continue;
        }

        pids[i] = fork();

        if(pids[i] == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            continue;
        }

        if(pids[i] == 0)
        {
            // CHILD

            // closing reading end
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            srand(time(NULL)+getpid());
            int r = rand()% 201 + (-100);
            printf("Child %zu: r = %d\n", i, r);

            // sending value to parent
            write(pipes[i][1], &r, sizeof r);
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            return 0;
        }

        // closing writing end
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < noc; ++i)
    {
        if(pids[i] == -2)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Pipe could not be created for child %zu\n", i);
            continue;
        }

        if(pids[i] == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child %zu was not started\n", i);
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            continue;
        }

        int status;
        if(waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not wait for child %zu\n", i);
            close(pipes[i][0]);
            continue;
        }

        if(WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)
        {
            int v;
            if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v) != sizeof(v))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not read from child %zu\n", i);
                close(pipes[i][0]);
                continue;
            }

            sum += v;
            close(pipes[i][0]);
        } else
            printf("Child %zu did not exit normally\n", i);
    }

    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me the output:

```
Child 0: r = -6
Child 1: r = 63
Child 3: r = 78
Child 2: r = 77
Child 4: r = -47
The sum is: 165
```

So the technique here is the creation of the pipes with the [`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html). A pipe
is a *unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication*<sup>[cite](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)</sup>.
With a pipe two processes can communicate with each other, but the pipe has only
one direction. In this example the child process will write into the pipe and
the parent will read from the pipe.

That's why before doing the `fork`, the parent creates the pipe, does the `fork`
and then closes the it's writing end of the pipe. The child closes it's reading
end of the pipe. Then the child calculates the value and writes into the pipe
the value it calculated and exists with the status 0.

After creating the children the parent waits for the children to terminate. If
the children terminate normally and with exit status 0, the parent reads from
the pipe and gets the calculated value of the child.

Btw, as [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085988/processes-in-c-for-linuxubuntu#comment85177873_49085988) points out in the comments, your method of getting
a random value in the range [-100, 100] is incorrect. `rand()% 201 + (-100)`
would give you values between -100 and 100, because `rand()%201` gives you a
value between 0 and 200.

---

**edit2**

> *OP asked in the comments*
>
> based on my understanding can I just return `randonNum` instead of `exit(0)` and do the computation where I calling `wait(NULL)` and `call wait(randomNum)?`

Yes, you can use the exit status of a process to send information back to the
parent without the need of creating a pipe. But I think this is not a particular
good solution for these reasons:

- the exit status in Unix/POSIX is a unsigned 8-bit value, meaning the exit
  codes are in the range [0, 255]. So if your random value is let's say -1, the
  parent process will see 255. In your case that wouldn't be such a problem,
  because you for values greater than 127, you can subtract 256 to get the
  negative value.
- You can only return an (unsigned) 8-bit value. If your child process has to
  send something more "complex" like a 16-bit value, a `float`, `double`, or a
  `struct`, you cannot use the exit status, so you
  are limiting what you can return to the parent. When you want to return
  something more "complex" than a 8-bit value, then a pipe is perfect tool for that.
- I consider it as a hack to use the exit status to send other information
  that is not an error value. The purpose of the exit status is that a process
  can tell it's parent that it exited without an error by returning 0, or that it
  exited with an error and the exit status has the error code. That's why I
  consider it a hack, for me it's like using a screwdriver instead of a hammer for
  nailing nails.
- Your `wait` call would be invalid though, because `wait` expects a pointer to
  `int` and you would need to use the macros `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` to get
  the exit status. But the problem of using `wait` in this case is that `wait`
  returns -1 on error and you wouldn't be able to tell for which child it returned
  -1 and how many waits you have to
  call to wait for the rest of the children. The children don't end in the same order as you
  forked them, so you would need to keep track which child has been `wait()`ed.
  It's much more simpler to use `waitpid`. With `waitpid` you can wait for a
  particular child. I personally prefer `waitpid` here.

So, changing the code to do the same without pipes and using the exit status:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s num_of_children\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    int noc = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(noc <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of children\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t pids[noc];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < noc; ++i)
    {

        pids[i] = fork();

        if(pids[i] == -1)
        {
            perror("fork");
            continue;
        }

        if(pids[i] == 0)
        {
            // CHILD

            srand(time(NULL)+getpid());
            int r = rand()% 201 + (-100);
            printf("Child %zu: r = %d\n", i, r);

            exit(r);
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < noc; ++i)
    {
        if(pids[i] == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child %zu was not started\n", i);
            continue;
        }

        int status;
        if(waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not wait for child %zu\n", i);
            continue;
        }

        if(WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            int v = WEXITSTATUS(status);

            // checking if the child wrote a 8-bit negative value
            // in 2-complement format
            if(v > 127)
                v -= 256;

            printf("Parent: child %zu returned %d\n", i, v);
            sum += v;
        } else
            fprintf(stderr, "Child %zu did exit abnormally, ignoring\n", i);
    }

    printf("The sum is: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me the output for 10 children:

```
Child 0: r = -59
Child 1: r = 73
Child 2: r = 61
Child 3: r = 98
Child 4: r = 18
Child 6: r = 31
Child 5: r = -88
Parent: child 0 returned -59
Parent: child 1 returned 73
Parent: child 2 returned 61
Child 8: r = 58
Parent: child 3 returned 98
Parent: child 4 returned 18
Parent: child 5 returned -88
Child 7: r = 53
Parent: child 6 returned 31
Child 9: r = -43
Parent: child 7 returned 53
Parent: child 8 returned 58
Parent: child 9 returned -43
The sum is: 202
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I didn't fix that because I focused on the communication between parent and children. I'm adding an explanation of this technique right now, I'll fix that at this point. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: how do I implement that in my code. I do not want to alter my code

Comment: @NeilShah don't expect from us to do the work for you. My code resembles already very much yours, but my has the correct parts that yours is missing. If you want to learn something, the read my code, understand what it does (I added an explanation to my answer) and compare it to yours. When you spot the differences, you transfer my technique into your code.

Comment: @Pablo I asked that question because I cannot understand your code.

Comment: @NeilShah then tell me/us what parts you don't understand, then I can update my answer and address your misunderstanding more precisely. But just saying " how do I implement that in my code." doesn't show any effort of your part. How am I supposed to know that there are things in the answer that are still unclear? Please don't take my criticism personally, but sometimes we have to teach less experienced  people using this site, how this site works, it's nothing against you.

Comment: Yea I understand the thing is I did not learn piping yet my professor only taught bit of shared memory but not in detail. based on my understanding can I just return randonNum instead of exit(0) and do the computation where I calling wait(NULL) and call wait(randomNum)?

Comment: @NeilShah - pipes take a bit to wrap your head around, but basically it is just a method for interprocess communication. It allows you to do what you could do with shared mem (in a loose sense). Your pipe file descriptors `in` and `out` are generally represented by an array `int pipefd[2];` (which gives you 2-elements one for `in` one for `out` in a convenient package). Here you have `n-children` processes, so above pablo used `pipes[noc][2];` to give one set of descriptors to each child. Then to use them, you close the end not used, `0-in`, `1-out`, in either parent or child, as required.

Comment: i am sorry but still cannot understand it

Comment: Think of pipes as being water-pipes between parent and child, but the water only flows one way. So if you are sending info from the child to parent (as here), you close the read-end in the child (because it isn't reading, it's writing the random value into the pipe), and in the parent, you close the write-end, because the parent process isn't writing, it's reading the random value put in the pipe by the child. The rest is simply the syntax that goes along with pipes. Some of the test for `wait` may look new, so I would suggest reading `man 2 wait` (link below)

Comment: [wait(2): wait for process to change state](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) and work through the example. And, if the `0's` and `1's` are not making sense, just remember the `STDIN_FILENO` is `0` and the `STDOUT_FILENO` is `1` (`2` is `STDERR_FILENO`). That may help with why you close either `0` or `1`.

Comment: @NeilShah I've made an update of my answer regarding your question about using the exit status to send information back to the parent.

Comment: I edited my question to update my code so now when i run that code it goes in infinite loop after second process

Comment: @NeilShah please don't change question after a couple of hours/days, create a new question instead. If you change your question, the answers might not make sense anymore and people in the feature will be confused about that and might even downvote an perfectly good answer which was fine before your edit.