# Processess and Infinite loops in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux

Here is what I am trying to do:

> Write a C program that takes an integer command line argument n,
>   spawns n processes that will each generate a random numbers between
>   -100 and 100, and then computes and prints out the sum of these random numbers. Each process needs to print out the random number it
>   generates.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int command,processCheck; // processCheck: to check if fork was successful or not and to 
    char * strNumProcess = NULL;// check the status of child process
    while((command = getopt(argc, argv, "n:"))!=-1){
        if(command == 'n'){
            strNumProcess = optarg;
            break;
        }
    }

    int numProcess = atoi(strNumProcess);

    int pipes[numProcess][2];


    int randomNum; // Variable to store the random number
    int randomNumSum=0; // Initialized variable to store the sum of random number

    /** A loop that creates specified number of processes**/
    for(int i=0; i<numProcess; i++){
        processCheck = fork(); // creates a child process. Usually fork() = 2^n processes
        if(processCheck < 0){ // Checks for the error in fork()
            printf("Error");
            exit(1); // Terminates with error
        }
        else if(processCheck == 0){
            close(pipes[i][0]);
        /** Child process**/
            srand(time(NULL)+getpid()); // sets the randomness of the number associted with process id
            randomNum = rand()% 201 + (-100); // sets the range of random number from -100 to 100 and stores the random number in randomNum
            printf("%d\n" , randomNum); // Prints out the random number
            write(pipes[i][1], &randomNum, sizeof randomNum);
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            exit(0);// Terminates successfully
        }
        else{
            if(wait(NULL)){ // Waits for the child process to end and directs to parent process
                int v;
                if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v)==sizeof(v)){
                    randomNumSum+=v;
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                }
            }
        }
        close(pipes[i][1]);
    }

    printf("%d\n", randomNumSum); // Prints the sum of the random number

    return 0;
}
```

The program goes in infinite loop after second process.

Comment: Note to users with closing rights: please don't vote to close this question a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085988/processes-in-c-for-linuxubuntu). The OP had a new question and I advice the OP not to change the code of the original question (because my answer there might not make sense anymore) and to write a new question instead.

Comment: Look again at  the first code in my answer in your old question. You are using the pipes technique, but you are **not** creating the pipes with `pipe(pipes[i])` before the `fork`.

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086298/1480131) very careful again. I have provided you
with 2 running examples, all you have to do is import the techniques in your
code.

So, you wanted to use the solution with the pipes, then read the code in the
answer again. Look that before I did the `fork`, I did this:

```
if(pipe(pipes[i]) == -1)
{
    perror("pipe");
    pids[i] = -2; // used later for error checking
    continue;
}
```

This creates the pipes, you have omitted this very important part of the code.
Without it, `pipes[i]` will be uninitialized and using `close` and `read` and
`write` on uninitialized  file descriptors is undefined behaviour and anything
can happen: crashes, infinte loops, etc.

The child part is OK, the parent part not so much. Remove the code of the parent
part in the `else` and put it outside of the `for` loop like I did.
You are forking and immediately waiting for the child to end. What's
the point of having multiple child workers when you start them sequentially
anyway, only after the previous child worker ends? Why bother with `fork` then?

The whole point of having child workers is that you launch them all at once so
that they run concurrently and do their work. That's why the `wait`ing phase in
the parent process should be **after** all child workers have been created and
launched.

Also in the parent block you are doing `close(pipes[i][0]);` which is correct,
but then at the end of the `if-then` block, you close it again. You cannot close
a file descriptor twice.

Also I explain why using `waitpid` is more reliable in this case, use that. You
also have to make sure, that the child worker exited normally. I know in this
trivial example this is true, but on larger examples where the child workers
might use `exec` to call other processes, you have to make sure that in order to
read a proper value from the pipe, this child has ended normally. That's the
behaviour that the parent expects.

So it should look like this:

```
// save ALL pids of the children!
pid_t pids[numProcess];

for(int i=0; i<numProcess; i++){
    // create pipe
    if(pipe(pipes[i]) == -1)
    {
        exit(1); // Terminates with error
    }

    pids[i] = fork(); // creates a child process. Usually fork() = 2^n processes
    if(pids[i] < 0){ // Checks for the error in fork()
        printf("Error");
        exit(1); // Terminates with error
    }
    else if(pids[i] == 0){
        /** Child process**/
        // closing the reading end of the pipe
        // child will only write
        close(pipes[i][0]);

        srand(time(NULL)+getpid()); // sets the randomness of the number associted with process id
        randomNum = rand()% 201 + (-100); // sets the range of random number from -100 to 100 and stores the random number in randomNum
        printf("%d\n" , randomNum); // Prints out the random number
        write(pipes[i][1], &randomNum, sizeof randomNum);

        // closing writing end of pipe
        close(pipes[i][1]);
        exit(0);// Terminates successfully
    }

    // PARENT 

    // closing writing end of pipe
    // parent will only read
    close(pipes[i][1]);
}

// now that all children have been launched and are running
for(int i=0; i<numProcess; i++){
    int status;
    if(waitpid(pids[i], &status, 0) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot wait for child %d with pid: %d\n", i, pids[i]);
        continue; // ignoring child
    }

    if(WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)
    {
        int v;
        if(read(pipes[i][0], &v, sizeof v)==sizeof(v)){
            randomNumSum+=v;
        }

    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read from child %d with pid: %d\n", i, pids[i]);

    // close pipe even if read fails
    // or child exited abnormally
    close(pipes[i][0]);
}
```